# expo, не работает ни один тип соединения с клиентом expo go

Tags: react-native, expo

Если создать новый проект и попытаться запустить его через expo go, то в tunnel выдает ошибку "Tunnel not found ngrok_3200", при использовании lan: "could not found. Network timed out", при локальном "Attempt to invoke interface method boolean com.swmansion.reanimated.layoutReanimation.NativeMethodsHolder.isLayoutAnimationEnabled() on a null object reference". У всех так? Это експо лагает?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, с expo беда, нашел старое устройство с версией expo 2020 года, плюс откатил ноду до 12.13.0 и expo-cli lj 3.8.0 и все заработало. Если ни одно условие не соблюдено, то будут вылетать ошибки.